# Selenium: How to read values from any file (text, excel or csv)?

Tags: selenium

Some of my project data needs to be changed every time i run the script. In order to have automated system i require to read values from any file and send its data as input to selenium script.

Comment: You want to use either Selenium RC or WebDriver for a project like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Selenium IDE, export your script to JUNIT ( java), then create a java project using that java file, then download the Selenium server library (jar file) and add to your project. then start the selenium server and run your script it should run successfully.
If it is working then you can simply use a java code to read files and set the values in the relevant places in your code.

ex: if you are using excel you can use jxl.jar library

You may refer my blog for more details. http://hrftools.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems like you need to run the selenium script for different values and values have to be read from a file. You can use [testNG's dataprovider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) to achieve this very easily.

Comment: thanks i was able to do the same with JUnit running on selenium RC