# Selenium - How can I get the current state of a checkbox?

Tags: html, selenium, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver, and want to tick a specific HTML checkbox based on the value of a column called `MovieType` in an Excel file. The checkbox should be ticked if the column contains `Yes` and unticked if it contains `No`.

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="trigger functionA();" tabindex="4" value="vnow" name="movie_Type"/>
```

How can I set the value of the checkbox if my Excel file contains `Yes`/`No` rather than `vnow`? The HTML is written by another developer, so I'm not allowed to amend it.

Here's my Java code for Selenium:

```
public static WebElement chkbx_selectMovieType(WebDriver driver, String value) throws Exception{
    try{            
        List<WebElement> chkbxMovieType = driver.findElements(By.name("movie_Type"));
        for(WebElement chkbx : chkbxMovieType){
            if(chkbx.getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                chkbx.click();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        throw(e);
    }
    return element;
}
```

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Just so that we're clear: Do you want Selenium to open a local Excel file (and extract the contents) if a certain check-box on the web page is ticked? If so, it sounds like you're actually dealing with two different things here: (1) How to read an Excel file using Java (2) How to interact with a web page using Selenium. It seems that you already have the second part working, so perhaps you just need to solve the *first* part? **EDIT:** Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202672) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190556) will help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read excel data in java, selenium testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190556/how-to-read-excel-data-in-java-selenium-testing)

Comment: Hi @GoBusto, I know how to do (1) & (2) as well, since the checkbox value in html is not neither "y, n, true, or false", how can I make it into  "y, n, true, or false" so in Excel file user is key in a readable value (e.g true), then selenium will checked the checkbox if excel column for value MovieType is true

Comment: OK, I see - so the problem is that the HTML file defines the checkbox as `<input type="checkbox" value="vnow">`, but you want to see Yes/No rather than "vnow" when you query the value. I'm not sure, but I don't think that this can be worked around unless the HTML file is changed. **EDIT:** Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201838/determining-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-html-and-php) will help - it says to use `checked` instead of `value`.

Comment: previously selenium can checked the checkbox (if the value in html is y /true). Now my html value is 'vnow', I don't wan set vnow in excel file so the checkbox will checked. I hope somethings readable like y or true

Comment: @GoBusto, you are right. Any suggestion solution since I'm not able to touch the html code

Comment: Can u try out with JavascriptExecutor to change the value as `document.getElementsByName('movie_Type')[0].value='yes'`. But this would take a comparable time for execution rather than just getting getAttribute('value').contains('vnow') chkbox.click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the solution would be to use the `checked` property rather than the `value` attribute, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

> checkbox: A check box. You must use the value attribute to define the value submitted by this item. **Use the checked attribute to indicate whether this item is selected.** You can also use the indeterminate attribute to indicate that the checkbox is in an indeterminate state (on most platforms, this draws a horizontal line across the checkbox).

For example, the following Javascript adds a new checkbox to the page and logs the checked-ness to the browser console:

```
"use strict";

var x = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

console.log(x.checked);
```

More information can be found [here](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/client-object-property-method/checkbox-checked.php).

So, it seems that you'll simply need to change this line in your Java code:

```
if(chkbx.getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase(value))
```

**EDIT:** See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8188579/4200092) for more information about getting the checked-ness of a checkbox using the Selenium Java API.

Comment: `if(chkbx.getAttribute("checked").equalsIgnoreCase(value))` then in excel value I should put what to indicate for check or unchecked action?

Comment: You would think so, wouldn't you? But not quite - as per one of the comments on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712), it seems that `checked` is a *property* rather than an *attribute*, so `getAttribute()` won't work. This is why my Javascript example uses `x.checked` rather than `x.getAttribute("checked")` when logging the checked-ness to the browser console.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want to set `y` or `n` in excel, not  html. if excel data is 'y', checkbox will be checked.

Comment: I think that you need to clarify the question then, because I'm honestly not sure exactly what it is that you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry for my poor explanation. In order to Parameterization of Selenium Tests with Microsoft Excel, at `MovieType` column in Excel, if user set `y` then MovieType checkbox will `checked`.
if user set `n` then MovieType checkbox will `unchecked`.
The problem is the HTML file defines the checkbox as `<input type="checkbox" value="vnow">`
I don't want set it as `vnow` in Excel, I want it set as `y` or `n`

Comment: OK, I've edited your question so that it should now (hopefully) reflect what it is that you're trying to do - please let me know if I'm still misunderstanding in some way. I think that the general concept of this answer still applies, though - you want to set the `checked` property rather than use the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

To know if a checkbox element's state, use the `.isSelected()` method. That will return a boolean value, and that can be the condition as to whether to access your Excel document or not.